# Why is angular displacement not a vector?

Tags: vectors, rotation, mathematics

How can one mathematically demonstrate that angular displacement is not a vector and is not commutative?

Comment: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/146897/247580

Comment: Welcome to Physics Stack Exchange! Your question already seems to be answered in the post linked by Anusha. If your question  is not covered by those answers, feel free to ask a new specific question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [If angular velocity & angular acceleration are vectors, why not angular displacement?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/146897/if-angular-velocity-angular-acceleration-are-vectors-why-not-angular-displace)

Answer (score 1):

look at this figure.

[image]

you want to bring the (x,z) axes to (x',z') axes you can do it by applying two rotations.
first rotation $\frac \pi 2$ about the x axes and the second rotation $\pi$ about the  z' axes. each  rotation ,can describe mathematically by a $3\times 3$  Matrix.

First Rotation Matrix

$$S_x=S_x(\frac \pi 2)$$

second Rotation Matrix

$$S_{z'}=S_{z'}(\pi)$$

thus: $(x,y)\mapsto (x',z')$ by multiply the rotation matrices $$S=S_x(\frac \pi 2)\,S_{z'}(\pi)$$

because matrix multiplication is not commutative, thus the angles are not vectors, but also you can't create the matrix S by addition the angles.

**Edit:**

$$S_x(\frac \pi 2)=\left[ \begin {array}{ccc} 1&0&0\\ 0&0&-1
\\ 0&1&0\end {array} \right]
$$

$$S_{z'}(\pi)=\left[ \begin {array}{ccc} -1&0&0\\ 0&-1&0
\\ 0&0&1\end {array} \right] 
$$

$$S=S_x\,S_{z'}=\left[ \begin {array}{ccc} -1&0&0\\ 0&0&-1
\\ 0&-1&0\end {array} \right] 
$$

and

$$S\,\begin{bmatrix}
   x \\
   0 \\
   z \\
 \end{bmatrix}= \begin{bmatrix}
   -x \\
   0 \\
   -z \\
 \end{bmatrix}~\surd$$